# text centering inside a container with 3 divs

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="Container">

    <input type="button" value="button" id="button1" />

    <div id="text1">
        some text here
    </div>

    <div id="TheButtons">
        <input type="button" value="button" class="MyButtons" id="button2" />
        <input type="button" value="button" class="MyButtons" id="button3" />
        <input type="button" value="button" class="MyButtons" id="button4" />
        <input type="button" value="button" class="MyButtons" id="button5" />
    </div>

</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#Container{
    background:red;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;}

#button1{
    margin:7px;
    float:left;}

#text1{
    margin:7px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;}

#TheButtons{
    float:right;
    margin:7px;}

.MyButtons{
    margin:0px 3px;
    float: left;}
```

As you can see in the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dX7eF/) here, the text is aligned to the left. The buttons on the right will have different text for different languages so I can't explicitly define the width of the third div `TheButtons`. How can I get the text to be centered between `button1` and `TheButtons`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the `theButtons` div before the `text1` div in your HTML. Then remove the float from `text1` and add `overflow:auto` to your `Container` div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dX7eF/2/)**

Comment: By reordering the elements, you float the first left, the second to the right, and the text within the text1 div (a block element that will center it's contents) will float up between them into the desired position. The overflow allows the container div to clear the floated elements.

Comment: Ok!! Very cool indeed! For now I had the buttons in English so I used a fixed-dimension width with text-align center to make it happen and I was basically looking for the opposite of display inline-block. Thanks for your answer: upvoted!